# Why wont my while loop work?

Tags: java

I have a task to:

> Create a program Password that prompts for a password from the user
>   and determines if the password is valid or invalid. There should be a
>   static method `isValidPassword` that validates the password (String) and
>   returns either true or false. A user has ONLY three tries to enter a
>   valid password. A valid password follows these three rules:
>
> - Must have at least eight characters.
> - Must contain ONLY letters and digits.
> - Must contain at least two digits.
>
> Use dialog boxes for the program. You must use the String and
>   Character classes for this program. You may NOT use regular
>   expressions. The program only needs to run once.

My output is correct however, it wont let me try again if I enter an invalid password.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Password {  

public static void main(String[] args){ 
int tryAgainCount = 0;

while(tryAgainCount < 3) {
    tryAgainCount++;

    String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a password: ");

    if(isValidPassword(password)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Valid Password.");
        break;

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Password. You've tried " + tryAgainCount + " out of 3 times.");
        continue;
    }

    }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Programmed by Alyssa Marquina");
}   

public static boolean isValidPassword(String password) {    
if (password.length() < 8) {   
    return false;  
} else {      
    char c;  
    int count = 0;   
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {  
        c = password.charAt(i);  
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {          
            return false;  
        } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {  
            count++;     
        }  
    }  
    if (count < 2)   {     
        return false;  
    }  
}  
return true; 
}   
}
```

Comment: Because you are `return`ing. It ends the method. Perhaps you should use `continue` instead.

Comment: Should my while loop be in the main method?

Comment: @ally Your `isValidPassword` should only test if password is correct or not. Logic responsible for checking amount of tries shouldn't be part of it. So yes, placing counting loop in main method could be solution to this problem.

Comment: @Pshemo I included your suggestion in my edits:)